# How Numpy calls C functions from Python

Tags: python, c, numpy-ndarray, cpython

Since Numpy is implemented in the C language for efficiency reasons, I would like to find out how exactly Numpy calls a C function, like `np.array`, from Python, as in which part of the Numpy source code is responsible for the calling?

I have tried to follow through the source code, the C implementation of `multiarraymodule.c` in the `numpy/_core/src/multiarray` directory and I focused specifically on: `PyMethodDef array_module_methods[ ]` to get an overview of the functionality the module will provide when imported to python and I also focused on:

```
PyModuleDef moduledef = {
    PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
    "_multiarray_umath",
    NULL,
    -1,
    array_module_methods,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL
}
```

which is the module name during its initialisation. I have also observed that: `_multiarray_umath` is imported into: `numpy/_core/multiarray.py`, the python module defined functions such as:

```
@array_function_from_c_func_and_dispatcher(_multiarray_umath.empty_like)
def empty_like(
    prototype, dtype=None, order=None, subok=None, shape=None, *,device=None)
```

followed by a lot of documentation and examples, then a return of:

```
return (prototype,)
```

I thought this is where C functions implementation must be called from, like of `empty_like()` function?

Comment: You'd have a much easier time understanding this stuff if you wrote a very simple C library yourself (one that just adds two integers or something) and created the plumbing to get that to work. There are many tutorials out there explaining how to do that. Trying to understand how it works from a mature library without even looking at the full source code is going to be very hard - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I do not have a problem with using the Python/C API - I have actually walked through an example provided in the documentation of Python, I have actually written simple scripts and fire up gbd, pdb to step them through. But, this time it seems that the simple details get twisted around in numpy. The idea is to try and contribute to an any open source project, preferably scientific since I’m into ML/Data Science field, be it documentation, and I was trying to understand how the Numpy codebase flows first.

Comment: Like many others (including some *Python* standard libraries) it's a bunch of extension modules ([\[Python.Docs\]: Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html#extending-python-with-c-or-c)).

Answer (score 1):

> how exactly Numpy calls a C function, like `np.array`, from Python, as in which part of the Numpy source code is responsible for the calling?

They are called from your code, when you write `np.array()`. If you try to disassemble a `np.array` call:

```
import np
import dis

dis.dis("np.array()")
```

You get

```
  0           0 RESUME                   0

  1           2 LOAD_NAME                0 (np)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              1 (array)
             26 PRECALL                  0
             30 CALL                     0
             40 RETURN_VALUE
```

Just a nice function call, that's all. Now if we try to disassemble the function itself, if it was Python, we would get its bytecode, as above; but we don't:

```
dis.dis(np.array)
# => TypeError: don't know how to disassemble builtin_function_or_method objects
```

So Python treats `np.array` just like it treats, say, `math.sin`: it is some binary code in a library, somewhere, that Python loads. Specifically, on my system it is in

```
site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-311-darwin.so
```

(On a Windows system, it would be a `.dll` file.) This file is the meat of the package `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`, and it has the function `array` defined:

```
from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import array
```

How does Python know to associate the function `array` there with the corresponding C code? `_multiarray_umath` module was defined using [`PyModule_Create`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4931) function using the definition [`here`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4381) as having certain methods, namely [`array_module_methods`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L4380), and among them:

```
{"array",
    (PyCFunction)array_array,
    METH_FASTCALL | METH_KEYWORDS, NULL},
```

referencing the `array_array` function defined [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule.c#L1699). When the module is imported, the shared library with the appropriate name at the appropriate place in `PYTHONPATH` is found and dynamically linked, and its functions become accessible to the program. No other Python code is involved in the call itself: `numpy.core._multiarray_umath.array()` directly calls the binary implementation, just like `math.sin(0)` does.

Tl;dr: module `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` is defined with `array` attribute bound to the C function `array_array` by a shared library named `numpy/core/_multiarray_umath...` in `PYTHONPATH`.

All of this is described in detail in [Extending Python with C or C++](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) and [Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html).

We can verify that this is indeed the `numpy.array` we know and love:

```
import numpy
import numpy.core._multiarray_umath

numpy.core._multiarray_umath.array is numpy.array
# => True
```

Now, how exactly it ends up being also assigned to `numpy.array` is a series of convoluted imports, getattrs, globals assignments and whatnot, which I don't want to try to trace at the moment, but it has nothing to do with how it is called, nor does it have anything to do with specifically C functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I see now that the functions are already available in _multiarray_umath, I presume the functions defined in the module numpy/_core/multiarray.py such as: @array_function_from_c_func_and_dispatcher(_multiarray_umath.empty_like)
def empty_like(
    prototype, dtype=None, order=None, subok=None, shape=None, *,device=None), are merely providing some form of documentation through the decorator applied?

Comment: `array_function_from_c_func_and_dispatcher` is defined [`here`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/multiarray.py#L78) as a form of [`numpy._core.overrides.array_function_dispatch`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/41e500bf1ece6ee0c987c6cd37379f56d581d98c/numpy/_core/overrides.py#L105). I am not sure what they are, I have never used them.

Comment: I investigated further on this matter regarding the decorators. From NEP (Numpy Enhancement Proposal) this in relation to the __array_function__ protocol for interfacing with array-like objects. The details are dense and I believe they require some time. The np.ndarray object defined in arrayobject.c file (last lines of the file) has the method defined. I will however investigate further on the matter since the documentation seems pretty well written, as it is for Python and it’s most libraries.